# C# Blazor and EF core Update-database error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I am new to Blazor and EF core as a whole. when I try the update-database in the console I get this message. I already have all EF core packages installed and for the last 9 hours I have been trying to figure out a solution.

```
//appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbConnection": "server= Assignment; database=InterviewAssignment;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}

//AppDBContexts.cs
namespace InterviewAssignment.Data
{
    public class AppDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions<AppDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
}

//Method in Startup.cs 
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
            services.AddScoped<EmployeeService>();

            #region Connection String
            services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")));
            #endregion

        }

first sentence of the ERROR
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Comment: This is usually due to a bad connection string. You might want to verify that in your appsettings.json file. If its a remote server then you might need to revalidate the certificate.

Comment: Do you really have a database server running on a host computer named "Assignment"? S.a. https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ (just to see a few examples)

Comment: Yeah I have, as that one was of the solutions on another thread. I also tried restarting the SQL server through management and made sure it has all properties that would allow it to work.

Answer (score 1):

As the others in the comments have mentioned, it is most likely due to your server name in your connection string. The easiest way to test it by opening SQL Server Manager, but if you do not have it installed then press `Ctrl-Alt-S` in visual studio (2019) and it will open the server explorer. There you will find the server name you need to use.

### Example 1: SQL Server Manager

[image]

### Example 2: Server Explorer

[image]

This should give you the server name. You can then also replace `Database` with `InitialCatalog`

Comment: "Database" and "Initial Catalog" (yes, with a space) are [entirely synonymous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). There is no need to advocate replacing one with the other

Answer (score 0):

The error where it says "Named Pipes Provider - make sure Named Pipes is enabled in the SQLServer config manager tool, otherwise it won't work. Also make sure that you enable it on the correct instance/client, that your firewall is open for the relevant ports and that your connection string is using the correct server name (and instance name)

[image]

Comment: Already done that. Thanks though!

Comment: And can you connect to it with eg SSMS?